# Why is there a limitation on the existential introduction in sequent calculus?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, sequent-calculus

In sequent calculus there is the rule $\exists \vdash$  $~~~~~\dfrac{\Gamma,\phi[y]\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\exists x\phi[x/y]\vdash\Delta}$ with the limitation that y is not used in any of the formulas of $\Gamma$ or $\Delta$ or in $\phi$. There's a similar rule for $\vdash \forall$ with the same limitation where I can imagine a contradiction. But doesn't the $\exists$ quantor always "searches" for the right element in our universe and therefore it is impossible to use a constant y which would create a contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Actually, it's **way** simpler than what I wrote below: clearly we have $\psi(y)\vdash\psi(y)$ but in general we don't have $\exists x(\psi(x))\vdash\psi(y)$. That is, take $\Gamma=\emptyset$ and $\Delta=\{\psi(y)\}$.

---

Well, $\{\varphi(y),\psi(y)\}$ proves $\exists x(\varphi(x)\wedge\psi(x))$, but $\{\varphi(y), \exists x(\psi(x))\}$ doesn't. The problem is that the *way* in which $\Gamma$ together with $\psi(y)$ proves something might crucially involve the specific variable $y$ interacting with stuff in $\Gamma$.

That is, it's not that the top *hypotheses* don't imply the bottom *hypotheses* (they do), but that the top *sequent* doesn't imply the bottom *sequent*. Indeed, we should expect that the top sequent isn't enough to imply the bottom sequent precisely because the top hypotheses are stronger than the bottom hypotheses.

Comment: Just some question here: I am no logician and do no logic research neither, but I am curious if the above deduction is valid to every system? As OP has noted "in sequential calculus" so other than this system there is some kind of different deduction rules? Sorry my question may not be well formed, since I am no into this account.

Comment: Hmm, but couldn't we in the bottom sequent choose x as y (which is a constant and therefore part of our universe)? Therefore there is an x which satisfies $\psi$ and the sequents becomes valid again?

Comment: @multiplex "couldn't we in the bottom sequent choose x as y" No. Just knowing "$\exists x(\psi(x))$" doesn't tell us anything about $\psi(y)$ - how do we know that $y$ happens to be that special element? For a concrete example, take $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ to be "$x$ is even" and "$x$ is odd" respectively, and set $y=0$; then (in the natural numbers) $\varphi(y)$ and $\exists x\psi(x)$ each hold but $\exists x(\varphi(x)\wedge\psi(x))$ fails.

Comment: @multiplex And I've added an even more egregious failure on the "$\Delta$-side."

Comment: So we are looking for a counteproof of $~~~~~\dfrac{\phi[y],\psi[y]\vdash \exists x(\phi[x] \land \psi[x])}{\phi[y],\exists x \psi[x]\vdash \exists x(\phi[x] \land \psi[x])}$. If we are setting $\phi$ and $\psi$ to the respective functions and $y=0$, then the first sequent is not valid, because 0 is not odd. Therefore we can't deduce a counter example from that. Do I have a mistake in my train of thought somewhere?

Comment: @multiplex Actually, the first sequent **is** valid. (Think about how the failure of a hypothesis in an implication actually *implies* the implication.)

Comment: Ok, potentially I have a misunderstanding, but according to my books a sequent is valid if all the formulas on the left side are satisfied and atleast one on the right side? This wouldn't hold in the above mentioned case.

Comment: @multiplex No, it's valid if *whenever* all the things on the left are satisfied then at least one thing on the left is satisfied. You should double-check your books (and if they do really say that, I'm very curious which books they are).

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it: Could we take the aforementioned definiton of $\psi(x)$ determines if an x is even and y = 0. So $\psi (0) \vdash \psi (0) $. That is trivial. Is $\exists x \psi (x) \vdash \psi (0)$ not valid anymore, because x could be an odd number in the natural numbers?

Comment: @multiplex Yup (and look at my edited answer).

Comment: (Although it is against the rules:) Thanks a lot for your help. Apparently it was a problem with the definition in my head.

Comment: @user284331 - Please, note that the rule is **not** the $\exists$-elim rule of Natural Deduction, that has no restrictions. The rule is the euqivalent of the inference rule: "from $Ax \to C$, derive $\exists y Ay \to C$, where $x$ is not free in $C$".

Answer (score 3):

The "trick" is the interplay of the semantics fof *sequents* with that for *free* variables.

We have that a sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is *falsifiable* if for some 
(non-empty) domain $D$ and some assignment in $D$ to all its free variables, it has the value $\text {False}$.

A *variable assignment* is a function $v: \text {Var} \to D$ that maps variables to elements of the domain.

Now for the counterexample. Consider the simple case:

$$\dfrac{\phi[y] \vdash \phi[y]}{\exists x \phi[x/y] \vdash \phi[y]},$$

and interpret it in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers with $\phi$ meaning "$\text {Even}$".

Thus, our rule amounts to:

$$\dfrac{\text {Even}[y] \vdash \text {Even}[y]}{\exists x \text {Even}[x/y] \vdash \text {Even}[y]},$$

and consider a variable assignment function $v: \text {Var} \to \mathbb N$, such that $v(y)=1$.

With it, we have that the upper sequent is $\text {True}$ while the lower sequent is $\text {False}$.

Conclusion: without proviso the rule is not sound.

Comment: I might be missing something... even with eigenvariable condition, there is a counterexample: $\dfrac{\text {Even}[y] \vdash \text {Even}[z]}{\exists x \text {Even}[x/y] \vdash \text {Even}[z]},$ with $v(y)=1$ and $v(z)=3$, no?